# How to unfocus GUILayout.TextField onclick outside

Tags: unity-game-engine, events, unity-editor

i have `myStr = GUILayout.TextField (myStr);` it's working fine but when I click somewhere it's not unfocusing automatically.

[image: Pic]

> How can I unfocus `TextField` on click outside?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Create a New Event and assign the current Event to it. check for MouseDown inside the Window and the region out of the field and set GUI.FocusControl(null);

For Instance, I have made a Window with multiple Regions one of mine is contentSection.

here's an example:

```
Event e = Event.current;

if (e.type == EventType.MouseDown && contentSection.Contains(e.mousePosition))
{
   GUI.FocusControl(null);
}
```